# How do I set container within React Material UI's AppBar Component?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

When I see MUI's default `AppBar`, its children looks so apart especially in wide screen size. The logo is located completely left, and other navs is located too much right. So Items look so apart each other.

What I want to do is like Bootstrap's component, I want to apply maximum width like below image. How do I set container within `AppBar`?

[image]

This is what I tried.

```
<AppBar>
    <ToolBar>
        <Grid
             container
             style = {{ maxWidth: 1170 }}
         >
         <Typography>Logo</Typography> 
         </Grid>
    </ToolBar>
</AppBar>
```

But it's not worked...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You may try using

```
<CssBaseline />
<AppBar position="static">
    <Container maxWidth="lg">
        <ToolBar>
            <Typography>Logo</Typography> 
        </ToolBar>
    </Container>
</AppBar>
```

Comment: This seems to be the most MUI answer here :-)

Comment: what does MUI mean ?

Comment: MUI stands for Material UI, a React framework packed with a lot of components

Answer (score 7):

This is how I do it:

```
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Toolbar from "@material-ui/core/Toolbar";
import React from "react";

const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  toolBar: {
    margin: "auto",
    maxWidth: 800,
    width: "100%"
  },
}));

export default function() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <AppBar>
      <Toolbar className={classes.toolBar}>
        {...}
      </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
function MyAppbar() {
  const classes = makeStyles(theme => createStyles({
    root: {
      flexGrow: 1,
    },
    appBar: {
      display: 'flex', 
      justifyContent: 'center', 
      flexDirection: 'row'
    },
    toolBar: {
      width: '100%',
      maxWidth: 1170
    }
  }))()

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar position="static" className={classes.appBar}>
        <Toolbar variant="dense" className={classes.toolBar}>
          ...
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use [withStyles](https://material-ui.com/customization/overrides/#1-specific-variation-for-a-one-time-situation) that is built in material-ui

```
import React from 'react';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { AppBar, ToolBar, Grid, Typography } from '@material-ui/core';

const styles = {
    toolbar: {
        maxWidth: 1170
    }
}

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <AppBar>
                <ToolBar
                    className={this.props.classes.toolbar}
                >
                    <Grid
                        container
                    >
                        <Typography>Logo</Typography> 
                    </Grid>
                </ToolBar>
            </AppBar>
        )
    }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(App);
```

Comment: It does not work because of flex-box. It won't be centered.